# Will an ETF immediately reflect a reconstitution of underlying index

Tags: etf

The fact sheet for [QQQ etf](http://etfdb.com/etf/QQQ/) says:

> The fund and the index are rebalanced quarterly and reconstituted
>   annually

So, if QQQ is just tracking the index, and tomorrow AAPL drops out of nasdaq100, the ETF will not reflect that until the next quarter/year?

Answer (score 4):

AAPL will not drop out of NASDAQ100 tomorrow. From your own quote:

> The fund **and the index** are rebalanced quarterly and reconstituted annually